# Golden tefillin for kings?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, gold

I heard in a shiur that Achav, as much as a רשע he was during his reign, actually was a very big תלמיד חכם in Torah knowledge and even wore golden tefilin all day long. Apparently all מלכי ישראל were required to wear them. Where is the source for this? I never heard this before and it sounds very interesting and I’m wondering if there’s halachot that pertain to such tefilin.

Comment: I never heard this either, and it sounds suspicious. Did your shiur have a source?

Comment: Apparently on here someone else found a source for Mordekhai wearing golden tefillin also. He didn’t give a source for it but he is very good at giving sources for what he says

Comment: The idea that Achav would wear tefillin sounds far-fetched. While he was a talmid chacham, he also erased Hashem's name from Sifrei Torah. He worshiped idols and had the prophets of Hashem executed. So why would he wear tefillin?

Comment: I think there may be a Kehillos Yaakov which discusses this.

Comment: Related: "[Mordechai wore golden tefillin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/137813/1368)"

Comment: @N.T. Where does it say that Achav did that? It says that Achazyah and Menashe did that. As for Achav, he honored the Torah so much that he was willing to risk Ben-Hadad's wrath rather than give his up!

Comment: Why is this far fetched? Many big reshaim like Women of the Wall or “rabbis for peace” also wear tefillin. Not something new that evil people wore it

Comment: @KapinKrunch They do it to gain legitimacy. Not something that someone trying to destroy Judaism would need.

Comment: @Meir I stand corrected. But the gemara before says he wrote on the gates of Shomron that he was kofer in Hashem, ch"v.

Comment: True. Yet that doesn't mean that he didn't keep other mitzvos; we do after all have the Gemara at the beginning of Chullin that discusses the fact that his kitchen was kosher.